# Адресная математика: на что влияет тип указателя?

Tags: c++, c, арифметика

Я всегда думал, что для адресной математики не важно, какого типа указатель - все равно вычисления будет производить в байтах. Но, кажется, я упустил что-то:

```
int main()
{
    int a=5;
    void *pa = &a;
    cout << pa << endl;
    void *ppa = pa + 12;
    cout << ppa << endl;
    void *sza = (size_t*)pa + 12;
    cout << sza << endl;
}
```

Результаты разные в gcc:

> 22ff00
>   22ff0c
>   22ff30

Я не понимаю, почему адрес указателя `sza` отличается от адреса `ppa`. Ведь в обоих случаях я прибавил к `pa` 12 байт. Почему так?

Comment: Ну так очевидный же вывод из результатов вашего эксперимента: ваше предположение не верно и адресная арифметика работает не в байтах. (И в С и С++ нет адресной арифметики для `void *`.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вообще, арифметика на типах `void*` запрещена в стандарте. Так что надо приводить к какому-то конкретному типу указателя, а не обобщённому `void*`. В gcc используется своё расширение (послабление), позволяющее интерпретировать `void*` как `char*`, т.е. выполнять единичный сдвиг (`sizeof(char) == 1`).

А когда будет уже этот конкретный тип, то арифметика будет на него и опираться, т.е. смещать адрес на указанное кол-во элементов соответствующего типа. Т.е. 12 - это не 12 байт, а 12 раз по `sizeof(*тип указателя)`, для которого производится арифметическая операция. В последнем случае `sizeof(size_t)`, что будет 4 или 8 в зависимости от разрядности системы (32 или 64 бит соответственно).

Comment: Ок, но как компилятор считает, на сколько сместить? Пусть это будет не `void*` - VC++ даже отказалась его компилировать - пусть будет `(char*)pa + 12;` или `(int*)pa + 12;` - результат все равно разный (могу поправить вопрос, чтобы это не смущало)

Comment: @digital-mag дописал в ответ.